# Flutter App, Admin has to confirm the Picture before it's uploaded

Tags: database, firebase, flutter

Has anyone experience with User uploads to firebase?
Is there a way to have the Picture confirmed by the Admin before it is Uploaded to the Feed where other People can see it?

Example: User Uploads a Picture to the App which will show up on other Peoples feeds (something like instagram)
But before it gets uploaded the Admin has to confirm it. Is there any way to do that with firebase? So its like a Spam filter for Images.

Comment: You can create an admin dedicated app, user uploads an image, it first gets to admin, if admin approves it is distributed to all users.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a moderation queue. Pictures from normal users are written to this moderation queue, where the admin can approve or reject them. Only approved pictures are then seen by other users.

This can be built with Firebase and almost any other technology. But the implementation depends a lot on how the rest of your app already works. I'll make some assumption on that below, since your question doesn't specify details. 
The most common approach is to have two top-level nodes:

1. With the metadata (such as the location and download URL) of pictures that still need to be moderated. This is the `moderation-queue` and it can be written to by any user, but it can only be read by
2. With the metadata of pictures that have been approved by the moderator. This is the normal `pictured` node that can be read by all users, but it can only be written by the moderator.

So regular users upload their pictures to Cloud Storage, and then writes the metadata about that picture to the `moderation-queue`. At this point nobody can see the image yet, as the moderation queue isn't readable to normal users.

When the moderator starts the app, they read the `moderation-queue` and find the image. If they approve the image, they write the metadata of the images into the regular `pictures` node, at which point it becomes visible to all users. And no matter if they approve or reject the image, they'll remove the metadata from the `moderation-queue` at this point.

The above assumes you're using the Firebase Realtime Database for storing the data, and Cloud Storage for storing the files. If you're using other systems, the approach can still work but you'll have to update the terminology.